# "They have taken it kindly." What does it mean?

Tags: expressions

I am interested in a synonym for "taken it kindly" in this context:

> [A. I. Root, “Letter 1 addressed to Wilbur Wright”, October 8, 1904](https://www.loc.gov/resource/mwright.03199/?sp=18)
>
> Dear Friend Wright:-
>
> … I have repeatedly already explained to my friends that I was not at liberty to mention what I witnessed and they have always **taken it kindly**; in fact, I have been a good deal disappointed because so few people, even the members of my own family, regard it as such a non important matter.

Did the friends of A. I. Root believe him, have doubts or "taken it kindly" has a different meaning that I completely miss?

Answer (score 1):

It means to be agreeable to something. In this case, to understand and not complain.

> [**take kindly to something**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/take+kindly+to)
>
> to be agreeable to something.
>
> - My father doesn't take kindly to anyone using his tools.
> - I hope they'll take kindly to our request.

The Free Dictionary

Comment: I have seen that definition but it is for "take kindly to". In my case there is no "to". I have a "take it kindly" not "take kindly to it".

Comment: It is a slightly different construction, but it has the same meaning. You can read it as "they have taken kindly to it."